# If $x$ is a feasible solution, satisfies complementary slackness, show that $x$ is a basic feasible solution.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Consider the linear programming problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\min&& c^{T} x \\ 
&\operatorname{s.t. } && A x=b \\ 
&&& x \geq 0,
\end{aligned}
$$
and its dual problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\max&& p^{T} b \\ 
&\operatorname{s.t. } && p^T A\le c^T .\\ 
\end{aligned}
$$
Under two assumptions, 1) every basic feasible solution to the primal problem is nondegenerate and 2) every basic feasible solution to the primal problem, the reduced cost of every nonbasic variable is nonzero. If a pair $(x,p)$, with $x$ primal feasible, satisfies $x_i(c_i-A_i^Tp)=0(\forall i)$, how to proof $x$ is a basic feasible solution.

I'm confused to prove this problem, because I don't know how to use the condition $x_i(c_i-A_i^Tp)=0(\forall i)$ in which $p$ is not certainly a dual feasible solution.

Comment: This looks like an exercise. What have you tried to do?